# How to animate collectionview insertions without disrupting other cells?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView in which cells are aligned to the left and cell width is based off of a string length. Similar to a tag view layout.

I looked up a quick tutorial on how to animate insertions: https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/306-customizing-collection-view-cell-insertion-animations

The cells of the previous row expand and retract to their original position.

I tried inserting cells without the animation and the same thing happens, and is due to the left-aligned layout with variable cell widths.

Here is the code for aligning my cells to the left in custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
        attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
                leftMargin = sectionInset.left + 8
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
        }

        return attributes
    }
```

and animating via:

```
override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)

        if insertingIndexPaths.contains(itemIndexPath) {
            attributes?.alpha = 0.0
            attributes?.transform = CGAffineTransform(
                translationX: 0,
                y: 500
            )
        }

        return attributes
    }
```

I expected it to look like this: 
https://imgur.com/cbWq6CI

But it looks like this (actual recording):
https://imgur.com/xfKZYnr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a this code in my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass:

```
required init(minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 8, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 8, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
    super.init()
    estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
    self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
    self.sectionInset = sectionInset
    sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I just removed `estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` and there is no extra movement.